# number puzzle: identify two numbers using sums of operations on the numbers

Tags: number-theory, puzzle

I have a number puzzle:

You have two unknown positive integers, lets call them $a$ and $b$, that are not equal.

You can perform simple mathematical operations on the individual numbers (lets say +, -, /, *, ^, modulus, bit-wise operations) and you can only work with integers, no decimals. But you can only know the *sum* of the results. So if $f$ is a function of a single integer ($f$ can contain multiple of the operations above and any other known integers you want):

$y = f(a) + f(b)$

You can only know the value of $y$.

The goal is to identify $a$ and $b$ (you dont need to distinguish between them). You can perform as many of these operations as you want, the goal is to use as few as possible. I don't know whether or not this is possible, but it seems like it should be...

EDIT:
There has been some confusion so let me try to clarify with an example (taken from Sridhar Ramesh's answer):

first we could choose $f(x) = x$ which gives us:

$y_1 = a + b$

second we could choose $f(x) = x^2$ which gives us:

$y_2 = a^2 + b^2$

See that each $f$ is a function of exactly *one* of our unknown integers.

Now, given the value of $y_1$ and $y_2$, determine the values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: It is easy to see that it’s impossible to distinguish $a$ and $b$.  Other than that it’s easy to determine the set $\{a,b\}$ in just one operation.  Two if you want to keep the value of $y$ reasonably small compared to $a,b$.

Comment: Agreed -- the rules here need to be clarified. Are you expected to distinguish between $a$ and $b$ or not? Also, the rules refer to "simple mathematical operations on the individual numbers" and then gives examples of binary operations, but then says $f$ must be a function of a _single_ integer. Which is it?

Comment: @Y. Forman: What do you mean by distinguish between a and b?

Comment: You wrote "determine the values of $a$ and $b$." It sounds like a valid answer is of the form "$a =$ this, $b =$ that," but an answer of the form "I know the set $\{a,b\}$ contains this and that, but I don't know which is $a$ and which is $b$" would not be valid. Can you verify/dispute this?

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion. No, you dont need to distinguish between a and b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot distinguish which is $a$ and which $b$ but

$$f(a)=2^a$$ works: write $f(a)+f(b)$ in binary and read the positions of the two $1$s as the corresponding powers of $2$.  This also works if $a$ or $b$ can be $0$ or can be equal

Comment: Very clever, I like it except for the fact that $2^a$ could be very large which might be a problem if I need to implement this (which I know was not a requirement for the puzzle, so this is a valid answer). I'm trying to think of ways to deal with the large numbers, given that $2^a$ will overflow.

Comment: @chuck1 - it is unclear what your ultimate objective is: it it is the efficient storage of $a$ and $b$ as two numbers then storing $a$ and $b$ might work, unless you know more about them

Comment: my application involves returning signals from multiple sources (i simplified to just two) on a single channel at the same time. and the signals get summed when they are sent. So maybe this is a data compression problem... so in a way it is about efficient storage. Perhaps i should put this up on stackoverflow too and see what i get...

Comment: Just to add: if $a=b$, then you'll get one $1$, hence you have to take the previous position

Comment: @asdf: indeed - read it as two of the previous position

Comment: If anyone is interested, i think my implementation using n-bits integers will look something like:
Using Henry's method, I will determine $2^{(a \mod n)}$ and $a / n$ (I'll have to use a second iteration of this method to determine both $a/n$ and $b/n$). Note that $a/n$ is rounded down. Then $a = \log_2(2^{(a \mod n)}) + (a/n)n$. Since we know that the binary representation of $2^{(a \mod n)}$ is a single bit, to find log_2 we shift the value right until it equals 1 and count the number of shifts.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very nice, very general idea:

Calculate $a + b$ (that is, the sum of the identity function on the two values) and $a^2 + b^2$ (that is, the sum of the squaring function on the two values).

From these, you can then compute $(a + b)^2 - (a^2 + b^2) = 2ab$, and thus compute $ab$. Now you know both $a + b$ and $ab$, from which finding the two values is simply solving a quadratic equation. I.e., you should now factor the quadratic polynomial $X^2 + (a + b)X + ab$ (using the quadratic formula, if you like), recovering the two factors $(X + a)$ and $(X + b)$, telling you your two values.

If you want an explicit formula, let $s = a + b$ and let $n = a^2 + b^2$, and note that $a$ and $b$ are given by $(s/2) \pm \sqrt{n/2 -(s/2)^2}$.

This works much more generally than over positive integers, and also works even if the two values are the same. In fact, a variant of this works for multisets of n many values, using sums of up through nth powers.

Comment: Here, I've used two operations instead of one, because I wanted to demonstrate this nice general fact. But I suppose this is why I've been downvoted; c'est la vie...

Comment: This is a great solution and does in fact meet my criteria (which was apparently confusing) I would upvote if I wasnt a measely 1 rep :)